# How could I make PHP sessions / cookies indefinite

Tags: php, session-cookies

I am using a login system that sets the session variables / cookies below.  Chrome, which awesomely lets you look at your cookies without too much trouble, apparently labels this as a PHPSESSID that expire "When I close my browser." Sure enough, when I log in, shut down the browser, and then open up a new browser session, I am no longer logged in.

How could I make it so the user stays logged in whether or not the browser is closed? I would like to make it so the user stays logged in (permanently, if possible) unless a deliberate logout is done.

```
$_SESSION['loginid'] = $row['loginid'];
    
$_SESSION['username'] = $u;
```

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at [`session_set_cookie_params()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)...

The first parameter is `$lifetime`.  Set that to a non-0 number, and that's how long they will stay logged in for in seconds.  If it's 0, it'll be deleted once the browser closes.  Note that you'll need to either store the session data yourself, or set `ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", $Lifetime);` as well (to prevent the server from deleting old sessions).  But beware that this could eat up a LOT of disk space (And open Denial Of Service attacks where attackers eat up all your disk space by just spawning new sessions continuously)...

1 year ~= 3156000 (seconds)

I'd honestly suggest implementing a "remember me" function rather than trying to persist the session indefinitely...  The remember me would use a cookie as well, but it wouldn't tie up server space for non-active users...

Comment: +1 for "Remember Me" instead of a long-lasting session.  Keep in mind that sessions can be [destroyed separately based on their age](http://us.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime), even if the cookie still exists.

Comment: Thanks ircmaxell and Charles... I am going to look into a Remember Me.  Any good tutorials or sites that either of you recommend?

Comment: There are a number of tutorials.  Try going through these: http://www.google.com/search?q=implement+remember+me+php

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set an expiration date in the future on the session cookie.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`session_set_cookie_params`](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to set the PHPSESSID cookie related settings.

```
//set cookie for 60 seconds:
session_set_cookie_params(60);
```

So you would just replace the value 60 with some arbitrarily high second value.